# Selecting bootstrap active tab headers for custom styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of nav-tabs where I would like the active tab to be colored (current active styling is too subtle). The tab structure looks roughly like this:

```
<ol id="event-headers" class="nav nav-tabs col-md-3 flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#event-0" data-toggle="tab">Event #1</a>
    </li>
</ol>
<div id="event-bodies" class="tab-content col-md-9">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="event-0">
```

I would like the active tab header (the < a>) to have a background color. My current css for it is:

```
.nav-link.active{
    background-color: black;
}
```

But it isn't doing anything at all. I have confirmed that hard coding that style on that element does make the color change, its just not finding the element or something with my selector. It seems like it should be pretty straight forward but I can't figure out why it wouldnt work. I assume its some trivial mistake that I'll be cursing myself for not catching.

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important with css property like the below code.

```css
.nav-link.active {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ol id="event-headers" class="nav nav-tabs col-md-3 flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#event-0" data-toggle="tab">Event #1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#event-1" data-toggle="tab">Event #2</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```